# Reactjs - Imported component does not render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Made my first Reactjs App using `create-react-app`. In my main `App` component i am   calling another component named `menuButtons`. It is imported but it does not display.

Extra info: In `App.js` when press CTRL key and click on `<menuButtons />`, VScode doesn't redirects me to menuButtons component.

Files Structure:

```
│
└───src
    │   App.css
    │   App.js
    │   App.test.js
    │   index.css
    │   index.js
    │   menuButtons.js
    │   registerServiceWorker.js
    │
    └───components
            menuButtons.js
```

My App Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import menuButtons  from './components/menuButtons.js';

class App extends Component {
render() {
 return (
  <div className="App">
    <footer className="App-header">
      <h1 className="App-title">SPEECH RECOGNITION SYSTEM</h1>
    </footer>

    <menuButtons />    
  </div>
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

menuButton Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class menuButtons extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Press the icon to start recording</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `import menuButtons  from './components/menuButtons';`  .js is not required

Answer (score 1):

The directory structure does not seem right. I recommend moving the `components` directory to `src`. Then refer the `import menuButtons  from './components/menuButtons.js';`

Comment: Yes, the components directory is in src directory. I messed up the padding while posting the question. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

menuButtons's directory does not seem right. its must be below example.

```
import menuButtons  from '../components/menuButtons.js';
```

or

you can moving the component folder to src folder then you can use

```
import menuButtons from './components/menuButtons.js';
```

Comment: Still not working. I have tried everything. Also updated the file structure.

Answer (score 1):

you must change your **c**omponentname to **C**omponentname
(and if it dosn't work try same issue on your component file name)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in `src` directory 
try without `.js`

```
import menuButtons  from './components/menuButtons';
```

Comment: Sorry components is in src directory. like src/directory. I have corrected the file structure.

Comment: @AmeerHamza changed my answer, too.. try it

Comment: No change at all :/

Comment: can you please look into debugger - from which location it is trying to load menubutton js file ?

Comment: try to initialize the buttons like this: `<menuButtons> </menuButtons>`

Comment: thanks @anshuVersatile, I have solved the problem. Actually it was not identifying the component because of camelCasing, I renamed the menuButtons to MenuButtons and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the component named from camelCase to PascalCase and it worked. But I am still confused because the naming convention of components in React-Native is upto user preference.

Comment: What Ameer Hamza meant is that instead of `<myProject />`, change it to `<MyProject />`. This got me too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite the name of your component that is not rendering, instead of  menuButtons change it to MenuButtons.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33408599)